# Laravel captcha image not working in production but dev is ok

Tags: php, laravel-4, captcha

I'm using the following package [johntaa/laravel-captcha](https://github.com/Johntaa/laravel-captcha) to enable captcha input on my site. This works fine in my dev environment. However, in prod it can't find the image (present it as a blank).

**Code**

```
//login page
@if (Session::has('show_captcha'))
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="captcha">Captcha</label>
        <p>{{ HTML::image(Captcha::img(), 'Captcha image')  }}</p>
        {{ Form::text('captcha',null,array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter characters'))}}
    </div>
@endif


//HTML output snippet in dev
<p><img src="http://localhost:8888/mysite/public/captcha?730518" alt="Captcha image"></p>


//HTML output snippet in prod
<p><img src="http://mysite/captcha?262091" alt="Captcha image"></p>
```

Clicking on the **dev** link yields a result but the **prod** link errors to:

`Call to undefined function johntaa\Captcha\imagecreatefrompng()`

File location:

```
../vendor/johntaa/captcha/src/johntaa/Captcha/Captcha.php
```

Comment: I assume your production `composer.json` is the same as your dev `composer.json`...so did you run `composer update` on your production server?

Comment: Hi there, I did a `git clone` of my repo and then did a `composer install`. I also just tried a `composer update` however, it didn't work.

Comment: Try `artisan clear-compiled` once if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely your issue is that the `GD` module isn't installed. Do a `phpinfo()` to check.

If it isn't enabled do:

`sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

to install it (on Ubuntu).

Comment: Yup that was it..Came across it via this thread: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10897

Comment: Awesome! Glad it was that simple.